# How can I use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" in Perl/Catalyst/DBI?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, catalyst

Maybe its too advanced for my apprentice level in Catalyst, but I need to port some functionality from the original system, and it is done using custom queries with the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".

**Can it be done using the Model/Schema/Result? Do I need to write my own FULL query?, how?**

*Here is the reason, just in case:*

- *The target table is a multilanguage and multiversion Preferences table with key/value pairs.*
- *I have 3 column indexes: theKey, theLang and theVersion.*
- *So, when I save theValue, it updates an existing row using those indexes, or create a new one if needed.*

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using DBIx::Class as your Data Abstraction class? You can then use the following statement:

```
$resultset->update_or_create({ col => $val, ... });
```